# Blazor Date Range Picker

Tags: blazor

I am using the Blazor DateRangePicker NuGet package (V3.3) from Sergey Zaikin. Its really good and works well but I cant figure out how to set the initial months when its opened.

At the moment it displays December and January, but being that we are still in December and there is obviously no data for January yet, I would like the calendars to display November and December.

Here is the code I have for it at the moment

```
<DateRangePicker OnRangeSelect="OnRangeSelect" SingleDatePicker="false" ShowOnlyOneCalendar="false" AutoAdjustCalendars="true" LinkedCalendars="true" AutoApply="true" ShowDropdowns="true" MinDate="@MinDate" MaxDate="@MaxDate" maxDateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy">
     <PickerTemplate>
          <div id="@context.ParentId" @onclick="context.Toggle" style="background:#fff; cursor:pointer; padding:5px 10px; width:250px; border:1px solid #ccc;">
            <i class="oi oi-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
               <span>
                    @context.FormattedRange @(string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.FormattedRange) ? "Specify a date" : "")
               </span>
                <i class="oi oi-chevron-bottom float-right"></i>
          </div>
     </PickerTemplate>
</DateRangePicker>
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Cheers